# Sharing DAL Code - MicroService v Shared Library

Tags: c#, enterprise-architecture

What is the best option for sharing DAL code.

We have a nice c# library that wraps SQl.Data.SqlClient methods like .ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteReader, ExecuteScalar etc. Its adds logging and helper functions around Parameters and generally returns nice pre-polutated IDataRecords. This is boilerplate code that we would like to share across lots and lots of our applications. But inevitably it does change.

If we go the shard library (DLL) route, then the downside is, if we update this code, then to avoid maintaining multiple versions in the wild, we have to update/release 50+ applications.
If we wrap this in a microservice, then we can handle the versioning there, but there is the overhead of passing data across the wire.

Any thoughts here, how do other people solve this one.

Comment: "best" is almost always debatable.

Comment: indeed, i guess what i am asking is how do others handle this?

Comment: It's worth noting, in many cases a service layer results in a *decrease* of data over the wire as compared to direct DB access ... (from the end-client's perspective)

Comment: *But inevitably it does change.* -> we've had a lot of changes in our DAL code in the first couple of months of a project. After that, it was already very stable to be distributed as a DLL among several applications. If you expect it to change a lot over time, it's probably not doing the service of a simple DAL anymore.

Comment: Also, exposing things like ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteReader and ExecuteScalar as a Microservice gives me the creeps. It's kind of designing an application to work with SQL Injection by design.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

However, being faced with an architectural decision such as this also has clear business implications too.

On one hand, building more indirection (and therefore more complexity, higher development costs, and more code to maintain) is a fairly quantifiable extra cost versus the most simple solution;  also consider the cost (or the efficiency) of KISS and YAGNI in real terms as well.

1. How much does it cost (how long does it take) to update your live applications?
2. How frequently do the inevitable changes happen?    Can your software release process be altered to reduce the frequency at which those changes are deployed?  (maybe even rolled in with other scheduled client-side releases?)
3. If the cost is high, are there any "quick win" improvements you could make to the deployment process to significantly reduce that cost?  (e.g. ClickOnce deployment)
4. How disruptive is the update process for each of your clients/customers?   (and again, are there any quick wins which could reduce the disruption?)
5. Who is involved in the deployment process who would be affected by the need to roll out the updates, and how do they feel about the cost? Could the process be handled by cheap/junior staff (if not already done so)?

While none of these are technical concerns, the "right" answer to many technical decisions often needs to be taken from a business and financial perspective.

If the business case for spending additional effort on a microservice isn't justifiable *right now*, that doesn't mean it won't be in future.   Consider writing the DLL in such a way which allows your decision be deferred to a later date.

That involves designing the interface to the DLL in such a way that it will be more easily interchangeable with a Microservice Client DLL.      The key to this is to ensure none of the applications have any direct dependencies on any of your SQL wrapper classes.   Use a "proxy" class with its own interfaces and its own DTO models (i.e. proxy models which are distinct from whatever classes are used by your SQL client wrapper).

While such a proxy class would be a bunch of boilerplate whose classes start to look like a hollowed shell of other existing classes, and whose behaviour is limited to mapping from one interface to another, the rationale for doing so is:

- Minimises future disruption caused by replacing your SQL wrapper DLL with a Microservice client DLL.
- Keeps a very clean separation between the SQL wrapper code of your DAL and your applications.
- Forces at least some of the hard work in building the Microservice API up-front without actually implementing the service itself.

Answer (score 3):

We built a shared Dll so I would recommend that approach.  We have a private Nuget Server where the component is stored so clients can get new versions at any time.  It doesn't change a lot.  When it does change, we simply update the code and then push a new Nuget package.  Clients can grab the new version from their apps since it is a Nuget reference.  We make it backwards compatible so old versions can exist with newer versions.

Your performance will be worse because there is now another hop to your data store if you go the service route.  If you have a lot of different clients  a service may be a better choice since both .net and java can utilize the service as opposed to a platform specific Dll.  But, if it all .Net clients I can't envision a service for this.

As @Ben has commented, we have implemented so the only reference the .Net client needs is `System.Data`.  All other references are in the component Dll which will be managed by the Nuget package.  So if the Sql Server implementation changes, the clients are oblivious to it.  If the dll is set up this way it will have good separation of concerns.

Sample Client Code Implementation:

```
            IDbCommand command = CommandFactory.Create("GetSampleById");
            command.Parameters.Add(ParameterFactory.Create("@Id", 11));

            var db = new SampleReader {ConnectionString = connectionString};
            var samples = db.ExecuteReader(command);
```

To Address @Vincent's comments below...

The column mapping is handled by the client, not the API.  The API merely executes the commands provided to it.

Reader:  Provides mapper.

```
    public class SampleReader : Database<Sample>
    {
        protected override MapperBase<Sample> GetMapper()
        {
            MapperBase<Sample> mapper = new SampleMapper();
            return mapper;
        }
    }
```

Mapper:  Maps IRecords to a DTO.

IRecord belongs to `System.Data` so no direct dependency on Sql Server dependencies.  If you wanted to map another column, just add it to the mapper...

```
public class SampleMapper : MapperBase<Sample>
{
    private const string Id = "Id";
    private const string Name = "Name";
    private const string DataValue = "DataValue";
    private const string Created = "Created";

    protected override Sample Map(IDataRecord record)
    {
        return new Sample(
            Utility.ConvertObjectToType<Int64>(record[Id]),
            Utility.ConvertObjectToType<String>(record[Name]),
            Utility.ConvertObjectToType<Int32>(record[DataValue]),
            Utility.ConvertObjectToType<DateTime>(record[Created])
            );
    }
 }
```

The utility class belongs to the API and handles the SQL Server to C# type conversions.

Of course, the mappers and readers can be auto generated for you automatically from the provided stored procedure and/or query for a lite weight ORM type of application.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your answer, but how do you handle OP's concern, which is that when the dll does change, all the projects depending on that dll must be released as well so they use the updated dll instead of the old one? Even if the API itself is backward compatible, it doesn't mean the implementation also is (for instance, maybe version 2 fetches data from a new collection while version 1 uses an older collection).

Comment: @Vincent - The internals of the API should not matter to the consumer.  However, if one changes the interface to return IEnumerable instead ICollection or something similar, then the older method access to should remain, so the existing clients can still work.

Comment: On the contrary I do think it matters. For instance, let's say I ingest data in a table in the column `foo`. My API expose the method `getFoo`. Project A use the version 1 of the library. When I call `getFoo` from A, I fetch the data from the column `foo`. Now, I change the implementation of `getFoo` to fetch the data from the column `bar`. I release the project B. Now, B fetches data from the column `bar` and A, since it wasn't released again with the newer library, fetches data from `foo`. There's a discrepancy between the two projects because one use the newest library and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

You do both. The shared library forms the basis for many of your microservices.

Of course then you need another shared library for using all your microservices. So you eventually wrap a service around that. And then you need a new library for the service. And so on, until one day you look back, and it's turtles all the way down `:D`